# Perl loop thru nested blessed hashref elements

Tags: perl, loops, hashref

I have a perl data structure similar to the following:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'admin' => '0',
                 'groups_list' => [
                                           bless( {
                                                    'name' => undef,
                                                    'groupid' => 'canedit',
                                                    'description' => 'Can Edit Articles'
                                                  }, 'group_entry' ),
                                           bless( {
                                                    'name' => undef,
                                                    'groupid' => 'webuser',
                                                    'description' => 'Can Access Content'
                                                  }, 'group_entry' ),
                                         ],
                 'trusted' => '1',
               }, 'user_info' );
```

I am looking for a way to loop thru all the groups in 'groups_list' and check if we have 'webuser' groupid in it. Any help is appreciated.

Also, kindly let me know if this can be done without using a loop.. something like searching for the string **'groupid' => 'webuser'** ..

Comment: Something would have to loop the hash to dump as a string, so either in your code or behind the scenes, looping is going to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bless`ing reference only add arbitrary type description to it and doesn't change working with it in any other way, unless you use `overload`, so exactly same loop as with unblessed references will work:

```
foreach my $group (@{$VAR1->{groups_list}}) {
   if ($group->{groupid} eq 'webuser') {
      # do stuff and break out
   }
}
```

You can also replace loop with [`grep`](http://p3rl.org/grep) if you only need inner hashes with data without their indices in array:

```
my @webusers = grep { $_->{groupid} eq 'webuser' } @{$VAR1->{groups_list}};
```

This will search entire list though. Use `first` from [`List::Util`](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) to only find first match.

Comment: except for breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @MkV, there's no mention if it would be used inside or outside class.

Answer (score 3):

This will loop through and find it:

```
foreach (@{$VAR1->{'groups_list'}})
{
    if ($_->{'groupid'} eq 'webuser')
    {
        print "found webuser.";
    }   
}
```

You can't really do this without looping, because your task inherently involves looking at each element.

Answer (score 0):

Since the groups have been blessed into a package, you should probably not be checking for the existence of hash keys directly, instead add a method to the group_entry class like this (something similar may already exist):

```
{
  package group_entry;
  sub get_groupid {
     my $self = shift;
     $self->{groupid}
  }
}
```

and since your data is also blessed into the user_info package, create a method on user_info  to filter the groups by groupid (your user_info class may already have something like this):

```
{
  package user_info;
  sub get_groups_list {
     my $self = shift;
     return @{ $self->{groups_list} }
  }
  sub filter_groups_by_groupid {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($filter_groupid) = @_;
    return grep { $_->get_groupid eq $filter_groupid } $self->get_groups_list
  }
}
```

and in your code, do something like:

```
my @webusers = $data->filter_groups_by_groupid( 'webuser' );
```